# HAML & Font-awesome; I end up seeing a 5 after the icon. I don't want the five on the button.

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails-4, haml, font-awesome

I end up seeing a number 5 after I display a font awesome-icon. I am using HAML.

[image]

The HAML code in index.html.haml file:

```
    {.container.service_providers
    .row
        .small-10.columns
            -@categories.each do |category|
                .button.tiny
                    =category.name
                    =if category.name == "Academic Enrichment"
                        -"Academic Enrichment"
                        #{fa_icon 'puzzle-piece'}
                    =if category.name == 'Academic Support'
                        #{fa_icon 'calculator'}
```

The categories are being raked from the CSV file:
[image]

Also, when you inspect element you see the 5 in displayed in the html document but not on the haml page. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change the `= if` for `- if`, that is the equals for a minus.

In Haml, using `=` means you want to print that output to the buffer, and `-` just runs the ruby code without printing the result to the buffer.

You're probably seeing the 5 as a result of the comparison.

Comment: Thank you kitopastorino, I am learning HAML while I edit it. That worked. Would you happen to know how to put the icon before the category name?

Comment: Got it :-) kept on playing around with it

Answer (score 0):

Search the CSV file for a "5", inspect to see that it's formatted correctly around every found5 ... no missing commas, brackets or quotes etc.